# set attribute inside zend form decorator

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I develop small form decorator in Zend Framework.

Inside it I want to change or set some attribute like add class to form element:

```
class My_Form_Decorator_Icon extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract
{

/**
 *
 * @param string $content
 * @return string
 */
public function render ($content)
{

    $element = $this->getElement();
    $element->setLabel('hello');
    $element->setAttrib('class', 'form-icon');
    $class = $element->getAttrib('class');

    return $content;
}
}
```

but nothing happens. Label `hello` added to form element, but no class added to element.

Comment: Your syntax looks correct. Have you tried echoing the `$class`? Seems like you tried that. If not, what shows up? If it does show up, then maybe you have a conflict with another decorator?

Comment: the form element showing up with no class inside, I enable only ViewHelper decorator but the result is the same

Comment: Does it not show up within the render code shown above? For example test `echo $class; exit;` just to see if the issue is in the decorator or not.

Answer (score 0):

The code was right.

in form element just put Iicon decorator before ViewHelperdecorator and it's worked now:

$userEmail->addDecorator(array('Icon','ViewHelper');